# iTextSharp Document Isn't Working After Deployment

Tags: asp.net-core, itext

i'm using iTextSharp to create a pdf document then add it as an attachment to send an email using SendGrid.
The code is working locally but after deploying the project in Azure this function stopped working for some reason. I tried to analyze the problem and i think that the document didn't fully created of attached due to the connection. I can't pin point the exact issue to solve it. Any opinions or discussion is appreciated.

Action:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GeneratePDF(int? id, string recipientEmail)
        {
            //if id valid
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var story = await _db.Stories.Include(s => s.Child).Include(s => s.Sentences).ThenInclude(s => s.Image).FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Id == id);

            if (story == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            var webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            var path = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "dump"); //folder name
            try
            {
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);
                    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
                    document.Open();

                    string usedFont = Path.Combine(webRootPath + "\\fonts\\", "arial.TTF");
                    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(usedFont, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
                    iTextSharp.text.Font titleFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 40);
                    iTextSharp.text.Font sentencesFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 15);
                    iTextSharp.text.Font childNamewFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 35);

                    PdfPTable T = new PdfPTable(1);
                    //Hide the table border
                    T.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
                    T.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    T.DefaultCell.PaddingTop = 15;
                    T.DefaultCell.PaddingBottom = 15;
                    //Set RTL mode
                    T.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;

                    //Add our text
                    if (story.Title != null)
                    {
                        T.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(story.Title, titleFont));
                    }
                    if (story.Child != null)
                    {
                        if (story.Child.FirstName != null && story.Child.LastName != null)
                        {
                            T.AddCell(new iTextSharp.text.Phrase(story.Child.FirstName + story.Child.LastName, childNamewFont));
                        }
                    }
                    if (story.Sentences != null)
                    {
                        .................
                    }
                    document.Add(T);
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    document.Close();

                    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    var fileName = path + "\\PDF" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHMMss") + ".pdf";

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    memoryStream.Close();
                    //Send generated pdf as attchment
                    // Create  the file attachment for this email message.
                    var attachment = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                    var client = new SendGridClient(Options.SendGridKey);
                    var msg = new SendGridMessage();
                    msg.From = new EmailAddress(SD.DefaultEmail, SD.DefaultEmail);
                    msg.Subject = story.Title;
                    msg.PlainTextContent = "................";
                    msg.HtmlContent = "..................";
                    msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(recipientEmail));
                    msg.AddAttachment("Story.pdf", attachment);
                    try
                    {
                        await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("{0} First exception caught.", ex);
                    }
                    //Remove form root
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The file was not found: '{e}'");
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The directory was not found: '{e}'");
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The file could not be opened: '{e}'");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });
        }
```

Comment: Can't say exactly, but I think the problem is with access to file system. ExecutionContext.FunctionAppDirectory the folder where source code is located if it's Azure Function. Also can't understand why you use '+' in Path.Combine method and do not use ',' instead. For example: `Path.Combine(webRootPath, "fonts", "arial.TTF")`. There could be an error with '\\' on different OS version and it isn't recomended to add them explicit.

Comment: *"this function stopped working"* - please explain what it does exactly. It's there an exception? Is there a blue screen?

Comment: Whenever I have this sort of deployment problem I do the following: 1) Clear out my local NuGet cache 2) Do a dotnet build -c release because I normally deploy in release mode. 3) run the application locally and see if it still works.  I usually find that it doesn't work locally when I do a clean build like this. Once I've determined that is true, I debug the problem locally.

Comment: @serhii i've done the line you suggested under suhaib's answer, but still the email is not delivered.

Comment: @mkl an email with a pdf attachment is not delivered to a certain address

Comment: I think you should replace Console.WriteLine with Function ILogger and register this service logs into configuration. Because, as I know, Azure Function skips logs from Console. After that you will know surely that trere are no exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is far from iTextSharp. I did a remote debugging from [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-debug-azure-app-services-using-remote-debugging-in-visual-studio/) article.
Two parts of the code was causing the problem.
First, for some reason the folder "dump" was not created on Azure wwwroot folder while locally it is. so, i added these lines:

```
var webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        var path = Path.Combine(webRootPath, "dump");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path)) //Here
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```

Second, after debugging it shows that creating the file was failing every time. I replaced the following lines:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                memoryStream.Close();
```

With:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fs))
                {
                    binaryWriter.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    binaryWriter.Close();
                }
                memoryStream.Close();
```

Hope this post helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

try to edit usedfont variable as bellow :

```
var usedfont  = Path.Combine(webRootPath ,@"\fonts\arial.TTF")
```

Comment: it didn't work unfortunately. The result of `string usedFont` : https://imgur.com/U4xWXoh ............ `BaseFont bf` was not created and some codes are skipped after this line.